# Hyperloop unknown or unsupported type (UIAlertController)

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop, appc-hyperloop, hyperloop

I'm trying out Hyperloop. And I'm trying to run a custom swift script I have in my project (like shown in the exmaple).

Here's my swift code:

```
import UIKit

public class MySwiftCode : NSObject {
    func SayHello() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message: "Hello, world!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    }
}
```

when compiling I get the following error message:

```
[INFO]  Generating metabase for swift MyFramework /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/src/MySwift.swift
Swift Generation failed with unknown or unsupported type (UIAlertController) found while compiling /Users/ophir/Documents/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/HyperloopApp/src/MySwift.swift
2016-01-26T16:40:22.195Z | ERROR  | ti run exited with error code 1
```

`UIAlertController` is part of `UIKit` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) and from my understanding native code ran with Hyperloop won't need to wait for Appcelerator to implement it. So I'm wondering why this code doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please make sure to use the latest Hyperloop version (at least 1.2.6). The following example code works for me (tested in the [hyperloop-examples](https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples) repository):

import UIKit

```
public class MySwiftView : UIImageView {
    convenience init () {
        self.init(image: UIImage.init(named:"swift.png"))
    }

    func SayHello() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "iOScreator", message: "Hello, world!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    }

}
```

Also make sure to run the app with iOS 8 and later. Since its a non-proxy API, you need to validate it on your own. To set the minimum target to iOS8, add the following key in the `<ios>` section of your tiapp.xml:

`<min-ios-ver>8.0</min-ios-ver>`